# How to use chart.js to plot a series of values against time with linear x-axis

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm trying to use chart.js to plot a series of values against time. For example,

X             Y
Day 1        10
Day 4        15
Day 11      40
Day 18     115
Day 22      80
 
etc

The part that's throwing me is that the values are sampled at irregular dates and I want the x-axis (time in days) to be linear e.g.
0, 10, 20, 30, 40, etc

Is it possible to have a scaleoverride: true for the x-axis, or am I looking at this the wrong way?
Thanks